# Application Security references

Tags: application-security

I stepped into Application security evangelist role recently. As part of my responsibilities, I need to stay abreast of security issues.  Can you please recommend some good websites that provide industry updates related to Web/Database security as well as on languages such as Java C# and Python. Appreciate any other advice as well to be successful in the role.

Comment: Slashdot is a good site for security as a whole.

Answer (score 3):

Wow, there are lots of great sites. I would recommend:

- [DISA STIGs](http://iase.disa.mil/stigs/Pages/index.aspx) for configuration of Operating Systems, Databases, and Web Servers.
- [Open Web Application Security Project](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Main_Page) - is one of the leading application security organizations, and has a website with excellent resources including the [OWASP Top 10](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013), [Application Security Verification Standard (ASVS)](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Application_Security_Verification_Standard_Project), and [Software Assurance Maturity Model (SAMM)](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_SAMM_Project).
- [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Main_Page) and [BSides](http://www.securitybsides.com) both have good local confernences in different areas of the country, in addition to the bigger OWASP AppSec conferences.
- [Microsoft Security Development Lifecycle](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sdl/) and associated material they have created.

Some blogs (roughly prioritized...I think Ars Technica would cover you so you don't miss anything major in the area:

- http://arstechnica.com/security/  (general news)
- https://www.schneier.com (mix of policy and technical)
- http://www.darkreading.com (general news)
- http://threatpost.com (general news)
- http://blogs.csoonline.com (general news, and many specialized topics)
- http://krebsonsecurity.com (cyber crime reporting)
- http://www.securingthehuman.org/blog (social engineering oriented)

[Veracode](https://www.veracode.com/blog) and [Cigital](https://www.cigital.com/blog/) also both have good blogs, although they are vendor flavored/biased. Cigital's Gary McGraw also has a good podcast, the [Silver Bullet](https://www.cigital.com/podcast/), which focuses on Application Security. I think the best all around podcast for security is [Risky Business](http://risky.biz/netcasts/risky-business).

I don't know of resources specific to security developments/news by language. You may want to watch the [National Vulnerability Database](https://nvd.nist.gov/) or other sources for new vulnerabilities (by CVE) associated with the software stack you use.

I'd be glad to hear additional ideas in the comments or added to this answer.